# how to debug the integration of ibus with chromium 67 (redhat 7.6)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, redhat-enterprise-linux, chromium, input-languages

I'm running on a RHEL 7 system. I'm trying to get Japanese input to work in chromium. When Japanese is selected from the ibus menu it works in the terminal and other applications but for chromium in particular it does not input Japanese characters even though the selection is still set to Japanese when I switch to the text editor window. I have ibus-1.5.17-5 installed.

I'm not seeing any errors in any of the /var/log's. Not sure where to start with this as I'm not getting any obvious errors anywhere. Does chromium have language packs that need to be installed?

Thanks